# How do I access a nested arraylist value that was created using datamapper?

Tags: mapping, mule, payload

i have a flow ftp --> datamapper --> logger --> database endpoint

the ftp waits for an xml file.

the datamapper has a mapping of an xml file, the schema was generated from a sample xml file using generate file schema to a map using the generate default, and then clicking create mapping.

now i send the payload to a logger.

when i print the payload in the console, the map looks like this:

: OrderIssueDate is {OrderHeader={OrderNumber={BuyerOrderNumber=11111}, OrderIssueDate=Fri Jun 28 00:00:00 EDT 2013,...

**edit**

What is the mule expression to extract the BuyerOrderNumber from that arraylist.

I have tried to use xpath, and it doesnt seem to work.

I have tried #[xpath('/OrderHeader/OrderNumber//BuyerOrderNumber') but that doesn't work because it is a map, but looking at the docs from mulesoft, it says xpath can be used directly on the payload to retrieve values.

I have tried #[payload[ 'BuyerOrderNumber' ] ].  but how can i get the nested level buyerordernumber.  Thanks.

configuration.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:jdbc-ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/jdbc" xmlns:data-mapper="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/data-mapper" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:ftp="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/ftp" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.4.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/jdbc http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/jdbc/current/mule-jdbc-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/data-mapper http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/data-mapper/current/mule-data-mapper.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/ftp http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/ftp/current/mule-ftp-ee.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd">
    <jdbc-ee:mssql-data-source name="Source" user="" password="" url="jdbc:sqlserver://path" transactionIsolation="UNSPECIFIED" doc:name=""/>
    <jdbc-ee:connector name="Database" dataSource-ref="MS_SQL_Data_Source" validateConnections="true" queryTimeout="-1" pollingFrequency="0" doc:name="Database"/>
    <data-mapper:config name="new_mapping_grf" transformationGraphPath="new_mapping.grf" doc:name="DataMapper"/>
    <flow name="FlowFlow" doc:name="FlowFlow">
        <ftp:inbound-endpoint host="192.168.200.2" port="21"  user="username" password="pass" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="FTP" pollingFrequency="10000"/>
        <data-mapper:transform config-ref="new_mapping_grf" doc:name="DataMapper"/>
        <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

        <jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" queryKey="INSERT" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="Database" doc:name="Database">
            <jdbc-ee:query key="INSERT" value="INSERT INTO [dbo].[Order_Header]
           ([Create_Date])
     VALUES
           (  #[message.payload.Order.OrderHeader.OrderIssueDate]
           )"/>
        </jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

logger payload output:

org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor:
[{OrderHeader={OrderNumber={BuyerOrderNumber=11111}, OrderIssueDate=Fri Jun 28 00:00:00 EDT 2013}}}]

Comment: I don't see a list only a map of maps in your payload, am I missing something?

Comment: sorry i am new to mule, so it is a map of maps

Comment: how can i access a map of maps? what is the syntax for that? #[payload['OrderHeader'['OrderNumber'['BuyerOrderNumber']]]]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve the `OrderIssueDate` field, use:

```
#[message.payload[0].OrderHeader.OrderIssueDate]
```

Comment: sorry about that, the message was cut off.

Comment: hmm it says it is of type arraylist, does that use a different syntax?

Comment: Message payload is of type: ArrayList
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. Cannot create input stream for class instance: 'class java.util.LinkedHashMap'. (java.lang.RuntimeException)

Comment: It's hard to help you without knowing the exact layout of the data you're mapping to :$ Please edit your question and 1) show the configuration you use to log the payload 2) show a more complete output of the logger.

Comment: hey david, the correct output shows up in the logger but for some reason when trying to insert it into the database i get "conversion from unknown to unknown is unsupported"

Comment: OK, I see the arraylist now, I've updated my answer. Let's see if it works for you.

Comment: Hi David, thank you for your help.  I plan on buying your book.